# Access outer object from inner object

Tags: c++, class, pointers, header-files

I have 2 (incomplete) classes, Level and Object, in different files, that look like this

Object.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Core.h"

class Object
{
public:
    Object(const Hitbox &hBox_, const Vector2& position_ = Vector2{0, 0}, const Vector2& velocity_ = Vector2{ 0, 0 });
    virtual Hitbox getHitbox();
    virtual void update();
    virtual void draw();
    virtual void drawHbox(const SDL_Color& color = SDL_Color{255, 0, 0, 255});
    static Core* core;
    

protected:
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 velocity;
    Hitbox hBox;

};
```

Level.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Object.h"

class Level
{
public:
    Level(const Vector2 &size_);
    void proceed();

    bool checkStaticCollision(Object* self);
    Object* checkBulletCollision(Object* self);

protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects;
    Vector2 size;

};
```

Level keeps all objects, object can do some independent stuff like drawing self or receiving input, but objects also have to interact with each other and do some level stuff like colliding, creating and removing selves, emitting particles, etc. How can I make it possible for Object to access Level? Incomplete types does not give required functionality so I cannot just use `class Level;` in Object.h, I cannot simply keep pointers to required functions since they are class methods and I it would be great if I keep it without void*.

Comment: Does your game have the guarantee that there is only ever a single `Level` in existence at a time? If that's the case, then a simple `current_level` in an `app` singleton is a very simple and efficient way to go about it.

Comment: `class Level;` isn't needed in object.h because the definition of the class `Object` doesn't mention the name `Level`. If you add a declaration of a member function that uses a pointer or reference to `Level`, then `class Level;` is sufficient. In your implementation file you'll need to `#include "level.h"` so that the function definition knows what `Level` looks like.

Comment: No, there will be multiple levels

Comment: Why does forward declaring `Level` in `Object.h` not work? As long as only references or pointers to `Level` are used in `Object.h` there's no need for the compiler to know the class definition of `Level` in `Object.h`; it's sufficient to include `Level.h` in `Object.cpp` assuming this is the place where you access the members of `Level`.

Comment: No, Object need to have access to Level functions. I've already solved it with include guard

Comment: @SavedowW It's important to distinguish, which parts of `Object` need access to those functions. Currently I don't see anything in `Object.h` requiring such access (neither in teh question nor in the answer). The part of `Object` that does require access is probably part of a file `Object.cpp`; You can add `#include "Level.h"` in that file in addition to `#include "Object.h`. The only issue is that you need to add the include to subclass implementation files too. You shouldn't get any benefit from using header guards compared to pragmas here btw.

Comment: @fabian, thanks, that works too, but is there any difference, except for being a bit cleaner and having access only from .cpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's the best solution, but, thanks to @PeteBecker, I've added (and also found out, huh) include guard so now it looks like that:

Object.h:

```
#include "Core.h"

#ifndef OBJECT_H_
#define OBJECT_H_

#include "Level.h"

class Level;

class Object
{
public:
    Object(Level* level_, const Hitbox &hBox_, const Vector2& position_ = Vector2{0, 0}, const Vector2& velocity_ = Vector2{ 0, 0 });
    virtual Hitbox getHitbox();
    virtual void update();
    virtual void draw();
    virtual void drawHbox(const SDL_Color& color = SDL_Color{255, 0, 0, 255});
    static Core* core;
    

protected:
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 velocity;
    Level *level;
    Hitbox hBox;

};

#endif
```

Level.h:

```
#include "Core.h"

#ifndef LEVEL_H_
#define LEVEL_H_

#include "Object.h"

class Object;

class Level
{
public:
    Level(const Vector2 &size_);
    void proceed();

    bool checkStaticCollision(Object* self);
    Object* checkBulletCollision(Object* self);

protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects;
    Vector2 size;

};

#endif
```

Comment: In `Level.h` the forward declaration of `Object` is insufficient, since you use it as type parameter of `std::shared_ptr` which needs to know about the destructor of `Object`; I'd remove the forward declaration there. Also I don't see the point in putting `#include "Core.h"` outside of the header guard; If the header was already included the compiler knows about the contents of `Core.h`...

Comment: Replaced `#include "Core.h"`, thanks. But `Level.h` does not compile without forward declaration, it returns `syntax error: identifier 'Object'`